# Very small computer for note-taking, with full-size keyboard

Tags: keyboard, portable

I am looking for a very small, lightweight computer with a full-size keyboard for taking text notes. Ideally it would be 500g or less including batteries for 16 hours of use. And writing text is the *only* use - a typewriter, if I could find one light enough, would be just fine.

[I realize this is not the place for product recommendations, and that's not what I'm looking for. Rather, I have no experience in this space, so what I'd like is to understand what kinds of equipment are available and what are the right keywords to plug into Google/eBay/etc. In other words, help me learn enough to do a worthwhile search.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a phone + a bluetooth keyboard.

I've used a Nokia E72 paired with a full size bluetooth keyboard and with a phone stand.
It lasted at least a full day, it was ideal for note taking as I didn't mind the small screen, and it also sync'ed well to the PC (but you can email what you write).

Comment: Or if you want a bigger screen, a tablet and a bluetooth keyboard. You can get bt keyboards the take little space but fold out to full size - just make sure you check reviews (or better still see if you can try before you buy) - if you are going to be typing lots even a slightly bad keyboard could be quite a pain.

Comment: Thanks @karate. In the spirit of your suggestion, it turns out I have an old Palm m125 in the junk heap which still works, and there are inexpensive accessory keyboards available for that. It also takes commodity AAA batteries which are super easy to deal with. I think that combo will work great.